# fine-tuning from an existing checkpoint: meaning of "steps"

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

In [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/scripts/finetune_inception_v3_on_flowers.sh) of fine-tuning an InceptionV3 model on the Flowers training set, there are two parts which say:

```
# Fine-tune only the new layers for 1000 steps.
```

after which an evaluation is run.

Then,

```
# Fine-tune all the new layers for 500 steps.
```

after which a second evaluation is run.

What does this mean in context of fine-tuning? I'm not sure what this concept of "steps" means or why they need to do evaluation twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A step means a gradient descent step on a minibatch of examples. The example tunes for 1000 steps and then for 500 further steps to show how the performance improves after fine tuning.